# How to override css properties from a specific module?

Tags: magento2, theme, overrides, css, less

I created a custom theme, that inherits from magento/blank theme. And I am able to override and extend css classes that are defined in

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/*.less
```

using the "Adding structured changes" section in the documentation (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html).

However, the property I want to change is defined in

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Newsletter/web/css/source/_module.less
```

overriding the class in my **_module_extend.less** doesn't work.

What is the right **magento way** to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you deployed setup:static-content:deploy ?

Comment: I'm in developer mode and using grunt to compile less files. It works perfectly with other css classes I extend/override.

Comment: Please add some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create `_extend.less` within the module inside your theme like so:

```
app/design/frontend/your-store/your-theme/Magento_Newsletter/web/css/source/_extend.less
```